# Transform an nxm XML table with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

In my app, I receive an XML table with a variable number of columns which I want to transform to with XSLT. The table has the following structure:

I have tried to transform it with the following XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:Informe xmlns:ns2="http://whateverUrl/" idOperacion="123456">
        <Resultset identificador="0" nombre="Nombre" numResult="1">
           <Header>
              <Columna tipo="VARCHAR">ColName1</Columna>
              <Columna tipo="VARCHAR">ColName2</Columna>
              <Columna tipo="VARCHAR">ColName3</Columna>
              <Columna tipo="VARCHAR">ColName4</Columna>
              <Columna tipo="VARCHAR">ColName5</Columna>
              <Columna tipo="VARCHAR">ColName6</Columna>
           </Header>
           <DataSet>
              <Fila>
                 <Campo>Val1</Campo>
                 <Campo>Val2</Campo>
                 <Campo>Val3</Campo>
                 <Campo>Val4</Campo>
                 <Campo>Val5</Campo>
                 <Campo>Val6</Campo>
              </Fila>
           </DataSet>
        </Resultset>
         </ns2:Informe>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

I have tried to transform it with the following XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="S:Envelope/S:Body/ns2:Informe/">
<html>
<body>
  <h2>My Title</h2>
  <table border="1">

    <thead>
        <xsl:for-each select="/Resultset/Header/Columna">
            <tr>
                <th><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></th>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <xsl:for-each select="/Resultset/DataSet/Fila">
            <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problems I have identified with my transform approach are:
- The `template match` does not go inside the specified elements of the XML.
- The value-of `<td><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></td>` in other tryouts I have made, printed "Columna", instead of the value inside the Column element.

Therefore, my question is: what I am exactly doing wrong that does not allow me to transform this NXM input XML table with this XSLT given the identified (and unsolved) errors in my approach?

Comment: You have `<xsl:template match="S:Envelope/S:Body/ns2:Informe/">` but there is no any Informe in the xml. Also `<xsl:for-each select="/Resultset/Header/Columna">` will not match anything because of leading `/`

Comment: Yes, I have deleted it by mistake, now it's fixed.

Comment: The posted XSLT cannot work, because it uses unbound prefixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing (it's hard to be sure when your XML example has only one row of data) that you want to do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:ns2="http://whateverUrl/">

<xsl:template match="/S:Envelope">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h2>My Title</h2>
            <table border="1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <xsl:for-each select="S:Body/ns2:Informe/Resultset/Header/Columna">
                            <th>
                                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                            </th>
                        </xsl:for-each> 
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <xsl:for-each select="S:Body/ns2:Informe/Resultset/DataSet/Fila">
                        <tr>
                            <xsl:for-each select="Campo">
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                </td>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Applied to the given XML example, this will produce:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. With your answer I am able to generate the fields inside the DataSet as expected, but the header field is not included in the table, I'll have a look with your solution in order to try to fix this problem.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the header field". Isn't the result above the result you want? Or are you getting a different result?

Comment: Yes, the result you got is the result I expect. With the header fields I mean the fields ColName[1-6], the problem is that it does not print anything regarding that row.

Comment: Well, if you're getting a different result, then you're probably not using the same XML/XSLT. I cannot help you with code I cannot see.